# headless RGBDSlam .PLY saver

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using RGBDSlam in headless mode and I would like to save all clouds in one .PLY file. the "rosservice call /rgbdslam/ros_ui save_all" service is saving the into a .PCD file. Is the a parameter that I can add to headless.launch?

I changed the source code in ros_service_ui.cpp . It saves to ply file now but meshlab is not able to load it and gives some error about shader. I guess I'm doing something wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33087/headless-rgbdslam-.ply-saver/) by [Amin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2235/amin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2012-05-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-05-03**:
Does it work to open them when you save via the GUI?

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2012-09-20**:
Also, can you post the change that you did in ros_service_ui.cpp? Changing from ".pcd" to ".ply" will not do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, there's no choice from the service call interface. Not sure yet whether to consider it a bug or not. For a quick fix, edit ros_service_ui.cpp's method saveIndividual(), so that the tmpfilename ends with .ply.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0